# ColorPicker view not updating when setValue() called

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, color-picker

The following code just creates a simple frame with a `ColorPicker` and a button, and *should* change the picker's value to blue when the button is pressed.

```
public class Demo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final ColorPicker picker = new ColorPicker();
        picker.setValue(Color.RED);
        Button btn = new Button("Change to blue");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                picker.setValue(Color.BLUE);
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        root.getChildren().add(picker);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

However, the button doesn't appear to do anything - further inspection reveals that the internal value does indeed update, but this isn't reflected in the picker's view.

Note that the first call to set the colour as red works just fine, but after it's made visible it never seems to update its colour.

Is this expected behaviour? It seems incredibly odd. If so, how do I work around it? The only workaround I've found thus far is to create a new `ColorPicker`, set its colour then remove the old one and put the new one in place - but this seems like a hideous workaround for something that should be a simple task, and is potentially breaking behaviour since any listeners on the old picker won't be preserved.

Comment: Does it work on [Java 8](https://jdk8.java.net/)?  I recall that there were many bugs in the JavaFX 2.2 color picker which are only fixed in the Java 8 branch and are not fixed on the JavaFX 2.2 branch.

Comment: @jewelsea Yup, just tried and it works as expected on 8, thanks for the tip! That's incredibly annoying that they won't fix these on the 2.2 branch - don't suppose you know of a workaround?

Comment: @berry120 you could manually call `fireEvent(ActionEvent)` - not pretty but will work, that's probably where the bug lies internally in versions < v8

Comment: @Reimeus Thanks for the tip, that'll be good enough for me until Java 8 comes out - and that's a heck of a lot better than having to create a new picker every time I need to set the colour!